# Site name - TeX versus LaTeX

Tags: discussion, design

Why is this site called TeX and not LaTeX? Does it have to do with copyright?

Comment: I have a feeling the real question is [what is the difference between TeX and LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-the-difference-between-tex-and-latex). See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/the-differences-between-tex-engines. LaTeX is, in extreme brief, a specific set of TeX macros, it's TeX what's underneath it all, it's not like TeX is a shorthand, or a way of getting around copyright, but LaTeX is the real full name, not at all. (On the other hand, the irregular capitalisation is partly to do with copyright.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The site name is formally 'TeX - LaTeX StackExchange'. This reflects the fact that TeX is more than LaTeX (plain TeX, ConTeXt, related tools, *etc.*). Calling it just 'LaTeX' would be restrictive, whilst just 'TeX' could put off LaTeX users: by user numbers LaTeX is the dominant form of TeX.